# iOS 7 app to create a password protected PDF or DOC file

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation, password

I would like to create a file on my iPad, password protect it, and email it to a colleague.  Is there a way to do this?  It would have to be in a format that is readable by others, like a password protected PDF file or a password protected Word file.

Answer (score 1):

molgar is right, just open in Pages app, set password and export as any file format and email it.

Set password
[image: Set password]

Open in another app
[image: Open in another app]

Choose export format

[image: Choose export format]

If you wanna email any file just download **[MailAnyFile](https://appsto.re/wTCk4.i)** from iOS AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

[Pages](https://www.apple.com/ios/pages/) allows creating rich text files which can be password protected from within the app. It supports exporting to PDF and DOC.

Answer (score 0):

[PDF Expert 5](http://readdle.com/products/pdfexpert5/) will allow you to password protect an existing PDF file (among other things).

[PDF Converter](http://readdle.com/products/pdfconverter/) from the same company allows you to convert a huge range of different files into a PDF.